# Why is my data not displaying when it automatically creates space for it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Please help, my code is supposed to display some dynamic contents to a table using react and ant.design I got everything working but it doesnt displaying the actual content but creates the space for it.

What I mean exactly is that the code, when i console the data it shows an array of 3 items, so it creates 3 rows on my table (which shows its connecting to the data) but it does not display the actual contents and its doesnt show any errors.

```
class OrderSummary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {order_items: []},
    error: null,
    loading: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetchOrder();
  }

  handleFetchOrder = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    authAxios
      .get(orderSummaryURL)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
          this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
        // }
      });
  };

    render() {
      const { data, error, loading } = this.state;
          console.log(data);

      const columns = [
        {
          title: 'Number',
          dataIndex: 'number',
          key: 'number',
          render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
        },
        {
          title: 'Event Name',
          dataIndex: 'name',
          key: 'name',
        },
        {
          title: 'Event Price',
          dataIndex: 'price',
          key: 'price',
        },
        {
          title: 'Quantity',
          dataIndex: 'quantity',
          key: 'quantity',
        },
        {
          title: 'Final Price',
          dataIndex: 'final_price',
          key: 'final_price',
        },
        {
          title: 'Total',
          dataIndex: 'total',
          key: 'total',
        },
      
     
      ];

     const datasource =  
        data.order_items.map((orderItem, i) => {
            return (
              [
                {
                  key: orderItem.id,
                  number: i + 1,
                  name: orderItem.item.title,
                  price: orderItem.item.price,
                  quantity: orderItem.quantity,
                  final_price: orderItem.final_price,
                  total: data.total,
                }
                ]
              )
                
              })


        return (
            <Layout>
            <div>
                 <PageHeader
                    className="site-page-header"
                    onBack={() => null}
                    title="Order Summary"
                    // subTitle="This is a subtitle"
                />
                <Table columns={columns} 
                
                dataSource={datasource} />
            </div>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
 } 


export default OrderSummary;
```

Here are the images of the console data and what is displays[image: 1].

Comment: Try logging `datasource` as well and update if you are seeing the correct data and structure.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'd try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your map function, for each element you return an array.
At the end of the iteration `datasource` will be in this form:

```
[Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
```

This is the reason you don't see the data in your table, you need an array of objects and not an array of arrays. You have just to remove `[]` in you return of your map function.

```
const datasource =
    data.order_items.map((orderItem, i) => {
        return (
                {
                    key: orderItem.id,
                    number: i + 1,
                    name: orderItem.item.title,
                    price: orderItem.item.price,
                    quantity: orderItem.quantity,
                    final_price: orderItem.final_price,
                    total: data.total,
                }
        )
    });
```